# How can I make this structure non-repetitive?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I need to make the following structure in a non-repetitive structure. Like the statement to run just one time. I tried to put "if" but that shows me the result 0.

I need to change this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int n, i, s, x;
    cin >> n;
    s=0;
    x=2;
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            s = s+x;
            x = x+2;
        }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, i, s, x;
    cin >> n;
    s=0;
    x=2;
        if (i>=1 && i<=n) {
            s = s+x;
            x = x+2;
        }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `x`, `i` and `s` variables, but you don't.

Comment: its unclear what you want to do. Please include input, expected and actual output in the question

Comment: @vahancho `x` and `s` are initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value to add (`x`) will be `2, 4, 6, 8, ...`.

This is [an arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) and there is a formula to calculate the sum of specified number of elements.

Using the formula `S_n = n/2 [2a_1 + (n-1)d]` with `a_1 = 2` and `d = 2`, the answer is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int n, s;
    cin >> n;
    if (n >= 1) {
        // s = n * (2 * 2 + (n - 1) * 2) / 2;
        // s = n * (2 + (n - 1));
        s = n * (n + 1);
    } else {
        s = 0;
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```